# Alternating bit protocol delayed packet

Tags: networking, protocols

In the alternating bit protocol, how does the receiver know the difference between a delayed packet and a correct one. For example if the sender sends a packet with seq#0, it gets severely delayed on the way there, so much so that the sender and receiver have completed 2 packets in between and the receiver is expecting the next packet with seq#0, and instead receives the delayed one. Should the receiver have a temporary storage of the last few packets to compare if it's just delayed or are there other ways to check?